# Animate Vertical Scrolling Text

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I'm implementing an About view controller in an app that shows modal when a button is tapped.

On the view controller I have a UILabel and some text displaying in there.  I would like to animate the text so it automatically fades in or scrolls upwards through the names of the team members who made the app - like credits scrolling at the end of a movie.

Does anybody have some similar scrolling working for text in a UILabel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIScrollView should do the trick.  A very quick way to make it loop infinitely is to have a blank area at the top and bottom that's the size of the scroll view.  (there are other solutions, [like this](http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html), or WWDC code (search for "street scroller" [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/)... but these might be a bit much for just the "about" view).

But with a blank on each end of the content, you can just loop like this:

```
- (void)loopCredits {

    CGRect frame = self.creditsScrollView.frame;
    CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.creditsScrollView.contentSize.height-frame.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 animations:^{
        self.creditsScrollView.contentOffset = bottomOffset;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // non animated scroll back, then run this method again with a perform
        // so we don't wind up the stack
        self.creditsScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
        [self performSelector:@selector(loopCredits) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    }];
```

The fade can be easily done with a masking image, or for a more realistic look, you can compute an alpha level based on the label's position with respect to the label's Y offset within the scrollView's bounds.

Comment: how do I add text from my .rtf or .txt file to a UIScrollView?

Comment: Read it into strings, then set a UILabel .text or UITextView.text (with .editable=NO) with the strings that were read.  Your question says you have a label with text in it (presumably your about text from the file).  Put that label in the scroll view.